# Can be block the external drive in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

My target is block some external drives, ex: illegal drive on Blacklist. In Cocoa, it can be done? Or need to block by setting permission on Mac OS? Can you give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You sure will be able to warn user, but not block them.

Comment: Is there no way to block it? I mean If user pluggin this drive, it will be force eject, do not allow user open this drive. Can be done?

Comment: Is your goal is to submit this app in AppStore?

Comment: Yes,submit this app in Appstore. Appstore will deny my app?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think is to user bash script.

```
drutil eject -drive external
```

But I am sure this type of behaviour leads to frustration for the user. So Apple might reject the app.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a kernel extension or create managed user accounts. 
None of that is getting into the Mac App Store.

Comment: Can you explain more? I dont know clearly what you mean. You mean I need to write a bash script?

Comment: Can you guide me how to write a kernel extension ? thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at I/O Kit. Put on your C++ helmet.

Comment: I can do anything with the external drive as eject, block it by using I/O Kit?

Comment: Read it. If you want to do this you have a lot of homework to do.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine Apple approving it, but you can (with appropriate authorization), write to the `/etc/fstab` And instruct the mounting code not to auto-mount devices with a specific UUID.  We use this on a machine at the office to keep our clone of the boot drive from accidentally mounting at startup.   In this case, you can force mounting manually with Disk Utility, as it is recognized, but not mounted.

The line looks like:

```
UUID=xxxxxxx  none  hfs  rw,noauto
```

Where xxxxxxxx is the UUID of the drive.